# Game center achievements localization

Tags: ios, localization, game-center, achievements

When adding achievements do you have to provide achievements in all languages that is supported by your game?  Is this required when entering them or when your app goes to approval?

Answer (score 0):

The localization for achievements needs to be done in iTunes Connect when configuring Game Center achievements for your application.

For each achievement, you provide different values required (reference name, achievement id etc). For each language you plan to localize the achievement into, you provide data for the localized title, description, text before and after the achievement is earned.

More details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html)

Comment: I found nowhere that states if it is required though.  "Further, for each language you plan to localize the achievement into, you provide data for all of the properties listed in Table 5-2."

Comment: From the question I understood you asked where you need to enter this info. You are right, it doesn't mention anywhere that this info is mandatory.